# Parameters in MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to create a MySQL stored procedure (SP) with input parameters.

However, the number of parameters cannot be determined at the time of writing the SP.
(The scenario is that the users will have multiple options to choose. The options chosen will form the search criteria:

```
select ... 
where prod_category = option1 && option2 && option3 &&...
```

So, if someone chooses only option1 and option2, only 2 parameters will be sent. Sometimes it may be 50+ options are chosen and hence 50+ parameters will have to be sent.)

So, I have 3 questions:
1. Can I handle such a scenario using MySQL stored procedures (SP)?
2. Is the SP the professional way to handle such scenario?
3. If SP is not the professional way to handle these scenarios, is there anything else that will handle these searches efficiently? The search is the core functionality of my application.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If you describe more clearly what you are trying to do I'm sure people here will come with the best solution for your case! However you need to give a bit more detail if you are really looking for the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL stored procedures accept only a fixed number of arguments. You can build your list of parameters and values delimited on a single string parameter and then process them on your procedure, or use your application language to build the query instead.

From http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,154749,155001#msg-155001

> No, MySQL sprocs accept only a fixed number of arguments. ISO SQL is
>   somewhat optimised for correct RDBMS logic (unless you were to ask EF
>   Codd, CJ Date or Fabian Pascal), but in many ways SQL is quite
>   literal, so if SQL seems to make what you are trying to do very
>   difficult, it could be that your design needs another look, in this
>   case aspects of the design that require repeated multiple ad hoc
>   deletions.
>
> If such deletions are unavoidable, here are three options. First, in
>   an application language build the delete query to include
>   comma-delimited string of IDs. Second, pass such a string to an sproc
>   that PREPAREs the query using such a string. Third, populate a temp
>   table with the target IDs and write a simple join query that deletes
>   the joined IDs.

Comment: Hmm...interesting thought about passing a string and then breaking the string down within the procedure. My only concern is whether it is realistic solution for a site that is likely to have 50 to 100 concurrent users. Also, the output will be a CSV file. Also, I guess the part about the deletions are not relevant to me.

Comment: In that case, depending on the maximum amount of possible parameters, you may also want to consider coding your procedure with all of them and leave those you are not using blank, or even read them from a temp table...

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of great reasons to use stored procedures.  Here's [an article](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/mysql-and-stored-procedures/5178706) that lists some.  Hopefully that will address the "professionalism" question.

As for the passing of parameters, I don't believe you can have a variable list.

A long time ago, I saw it "done" by writing the values to a table and having the stored procedure read them back in.  (Use a session_id in the table and then pass that to the procedure).

As for "efficiency", it depends on your definition.  There might be a slight speed benefit to the stored procedures, but I wouldn't worry about that.  What did you mean?